# How to declare class with auto property of type list of strings in F#?

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I have trouble to understand how should I define class in F# where I have properties without already declared value. Something equivalent to c# code:

```cs
class Entity 
{
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public List<string> Favorites { get; set;}
}
```

I can only declare type with defined type like

```
type Entity = 
    member val Name = "" with get, set
```

when I assign null the type of Name will be null.

Comment: F# doesn't like nulls. That's one of its greatest advantages.  Even ORMs return `string option` if a value is NULL. Use `Option<string>.None` instead.

Comment: Did you try `member val Name: string = null with get, set` and `member val Favorites: ResizeArray<string> = null with get, set`?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Is the question about null, or string list? Or both? Also, `null` is not a type.

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't precise enough. I'm little confused because I'm creating class which will be consumed by another library. Previously it was written in c#. That is why I wonder if there is some special logic when some properties are null or empty value. Same with Lists if they are none value or null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `null` values are not recommended in F#, so it is a good idea to avoid them if you can. F# types also do not allow `null` by default, so if you are using immutable F# `list` type, then your best option is to initialise the property to an empty list:

```
type Entity() = 
    member val Name = "" with get, set
    member val Favorities : list<string> = [] with get, set
```

Note that I added a type annotation `list<string>` because the compiler cannot infer that the empty list contains strings just from the code and you'd end up with `list<obj>` otherwise.

The C# `List` type is abbreviated in F# as `ResizeArray` and as this is a .NET type, it is possible to initialise properties of this type to `null`:

```
type Entity() = 
    member val Name = "" with get, set
    member val Favorities : ResizeArray<string> = null with get, set
```

I suppose this might be useful if you are using some non-F#-friendly ORM and similar things, but otherwise, using this will probably cause you a lot of pain and unexpected errors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I love the fact that F# is trying not to use nulls but in .net framework environment it is hard totally stop.

Answer (score 3):

The closest F# equivalent to that C# code is this:

```
type Entity() = 
    member val Name = Unchecked.defaultof<string> with get, set
    member val Favorites = Unchecked.defaultof<string list> with get, set
```

However, this is bad F#, which is why it is intentionally designed to look ugly. F# discourages the use of default values, nullable references and mutation.

Therefore, you should either decide on some reasonable defaults:

```
type Entity() = 
    member val Name = "" with get, set
    member val Favorites = [] with get, set
```

Or you should make values explicitly optional using the `Option` type and use `None` as the default, avoiding null reference exceptions at runtime:

```
type Entity() = 
    member val Name = None : string option with get, set
    member val Favorites = None : string list option with get, set
```

Note: The `list` that I use above is not the same as a C# `List`.

Comment: Yes... you right it looks totally ugly but what is best option when you for example deserialize json using Newtonsoft library? They will not work with record or tuples. In my case i will use default values and see what happen. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I see in your comments that your reason for using `member val` is for Newtonsoft.Json. Using it with F# records used to be a problem, but now it works perfectly fine. The following was tested with Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.3:

```
type Foo =
    {
        x: int
        y: float
    }

open Newtonsoft.Json

let foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>("{\"x\":1,\"y\":1.2}")
printfn "%A" foo
// {x = 1;
//  y = 1.2;}
```

And for serialization libraries that require a default constructor and mutable fields, you can put the `[<CLIMutable>]` attribute on a record and it will provide those (but invisible from F#, to keep safety guarantees).